# Transcoding ts of m3u8 to multi bitrate ts. Causes player stuck due to overlap

Tags: ffmpeg, python, hls, ffprobe

I have live M3u8. Woukd like to convert into multiprofile m3u8 and master.m3u8.
we have achieved this using python script to populate multiprofile index.m3u8 and master.m3u8.

when we are transcoding ts from input m3u8 stream. the player gives error that overlapping between fragments detected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ncLk.png]

basically what i could see pts of stream changes and it not monotonically increasing which is leading to gap.

Possible solution
preserving the pts and dts value. using -copyts but didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.